# What do you call the property where a set is closed under an operation infinitely many times?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

My understanding of the closure of a set $S$ under an operation $\oplus$ is that applying $\oplus$ to elements of $S$ yields only other elements of $S$. However, in my undergraduate topology class we recently came across the concept that, although a given topology $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under union and intersection, while the union of infinitely many elements of $\mathcal{T}$ is necessarily a member of $\mathcal{T}$, the intersection is not. Is there a concise way to express this? (i.e., " $\mathcal{T}$ is infinitely closed under the operation $\cup$", or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is usually expressed is to say that $\mathcal{T}$ is "closed under arbitrary unions". See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431942/why-do-we-require-topologies-are-closed-under-arbitrary-union) (or google the phrase).

Similarly, if we only allowed (say) countable unions, we would say $\mathcal{T}$ is "closed under countable unions". For instance, in a given topology the class of [$F_\sigma$ sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set) is closed under countable unions.

Comment: ...and the other half is usually "closed under finite intersections".